# Circuit with LEDs, SW520D switch and TP4056

Tags: led, circuit-analysis

I'm willing to reproduce (and modify a bit) a French YouTuber's project. ([Here is the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgVMxwe8NDo))

Except that I want to get rid of the ATtiny.

It's a circuit with 2 LEDs powered by a battery. The circuit has an SW520D switch. The battery is rechargeable with a TP4056 which is itself connected to a wireless charger because all the components will be immersed in epoxy.

As I've deleted the ATtiny I think that I should add some resistors to the circuit... So here is the idea:

[image]

[My LEDs](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/33011785949.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.6be03c00folxW6&mp=1) are working within 1W and shouldn't be powered with more than 3.1V.

[My lipo battery](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/1005001793787696.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.7a556c37ehNZiF) deliver 3.7V and 1000mAh.

In order to calculate the resistance to choose I did the following:

[image]

**Does those calculus sounds right?**

**Should I consider that the lipo can deliver more than 3.7V at full charge?**

Then if I take 4V, my resistors should lower the voltage of 0.9V and not 0.6V so R = 2.79 Ohms.

**To be 100% sure that I don't burn my LEDs should I take some 3 Ohms resistances? Won't the brightness of the LEDs be affected?**

Then if the current is 0.323 A in a LED branch then it should be 0.646 in the battery's one right?

**Does it mean that at full charge the battery will last 1Ah/0.64 = 1.55 h?**

In the comments of the video someone criticizes the circuit and says that she (YouTuber) should use some transistor or capacitor... Which exceeds by far my skills... **Do I need those things?**

Comment: It would help to have a schematic or block diagram of the overall project rather than having to review a video. Check https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/105136/2028 for more information.

Comment: To sum up, you have a pre-built board to accept power from an inductor (for wireless charging), a LiPo battery charger with on-board USB port, a LiPo battery, and two LEDs which should be lit only when the tilt switch is activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems mostly about the current-limiting resistor choice for the LEDs. The LEDs list the following specifications:

> - Tension (forward voltage): 2.9 - 3.1V
> - Puissance (power): 1W

There are *countless* [other](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/55823/2028) [questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/17179/2028) [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/28393/2028) and [calculators](https://ohmslawcalculator.com/led-resistor-calculator) on [web](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/led-resistor-calculator/) [sites](https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-led-series-resistor) about selecting the correct value of resistor for LEDs.

The [TP4056](http://www.tp4056.com/d/tp4056.pdf) has a max charge voltage of 4.2V, which means that the LEDs will have this maximum voltage applied when the battery is being charged. This is therefore the value you should take into consideration to ensure that the LEDs never have too much current.

If they are 1W capable, then using Ohm's law, we can derive the maximum current that they tolerate:

$$I=\frac{P}{E}$$

1W / 3.1V = 0.323A or 323mA

Using the maximum voltage we expect to see, 4.2V, subtract the LED forward voltage to determine the voltage that will be across the current-limiting resistor:

4.2 - 3.1 = 1.1V

And then calculate the resistor value using Ohm's law, knowing its voltage will be 1.1 and current 323 mA:

$$R = \frac{E}{I}$$

1.1 / 0.323 = 3.41Ω

3.3Ω and 3.6Ω are common values of resistor. To err on the side of caution, I would use 3.6Ω resistors rated for the power that the resistor will need to dissipate:

$$P=I \times E$$

0.323 * 1.1 = 0.355 W

Therefore, a **3.6Ω 500mW** (1/2 W) resistor would be recommended.

---

I do not know French, but from watching a brief clip of the video, I assume that the microcontroller (ATtiny) was utilized to add the flickering effect to the LEDs. Your project will just have constantly lit LEDs since you are omitting that portion. The comments in the video that you reference were likely pointing out that to drive that much current through LEDs, transistors should be implemented so that the microcontroller is not sourcing that much current.

[image: Screenshot of "schematic"]

As you can see here, the video shows a "schematic" where the LEDs are *directly* connected to the microcontroller, an [ATtiny84](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/8006S.pdf), which can only source about 40mA on a GPIO pin:

[image: ATtiny84 electrical characteristics]

It may be worth noting that since the microcontroller can only supply 40mA, the LEDs shown in the video are likely operating *much* dimmer than they would without that limitation. You may want to recalculate the resistors for a 40mA current if they are too bright. If you do that, you will also gain greater run time from the battery (see below).

In any case, it is good to omit this from your project for now. Trying to drive LEDs with the microcontroller at ≥40mA would quickly damage it.

Next, you are correct that in having two LEDs in parallel, if each branch is at 323 mA, the total current (supplied by the charger or battery) would be 646 mA.

Finally, if the battery is 1000mAh then it can in *theory* supply 1000 mA for 1 hour, or 646 mA for 1.55 hours. Note that batteries often will have a rated capacity at a given discharge. For example, an alkaline battery may only provide its stated capacity at a low discharge (like 20 mA). Drawing more will result in reduced total capacity. However, a LiPo battery tends to be able to deliver higher current, so I think you could reasonably expect about 1.5 hour run time. If you were to limit current to 80mA (40mA per LED as mentioned above), run time would increase to perhaps 12.5 hours.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You said that a 3.6Ω 500mW (1/2 W) is recommended but P= U*I so when the battery is charging P = 4.2 * 0.323 = 1.357 W then this power is over 500mW ... Is that a problem for the resistances ? Should I take resistances that can handle more thant 1.357W ?

Comment: No, each resistor would be able to handle 500mW. With the parallel branches being equal, they would each be dissipating only the power associated with their branch. When charging, realize that the battery is consuming (storing) energy, which is where some of that power is going.

Comment: ok thanks a lot again :)